# UITabbarController subclass & Badges

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have been subclassing a `UITabBarController` as below

```
@interface customTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

I have been initialising the controller from an array of controllers for `UITabBar` items.

I want to show the badges on `UITabBarItem`s which is a pretty straight forward process, but I am unable to view any badges. I have tried every possible way but with no success. The same code is working on standard `UITabBarController` sample code without subclassing it...

Comment: What code is in your subclass?

Comment: Adding controller and creating an array for Tabbar              forthTab = [storyboard4 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"messagesNavController"];
    fifthTab= [storyboard5 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settingsNavController"];
    
    NSArray *tabArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstTab,secondTab,thirdTab,forthTab,fifthTab,nil];
    
    self.viewControllers = tabArray;
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

Comment: When we take UITabBarController as above then it's XIB will not load (I assuming that you are using XIB with this). So any XIB component will not be take effect. Hope it clear you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try
`UITabBarItems` have a `badgeValue` property.

You can set this when your delegate method gets fired.

```
(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(SubClassUITabBarItem *)item;
```

You can get the TabBarItem #3 from the tabBarController with:

```
[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
```